# Rails Debugger issues like hanging, multi line, unknown characters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, debugging, activerecord, rails-console

I have been using rails 7 for the past few months. Everything is good except rails 7 debugger comes bundles with it by default. It has multiple issues in it.

- cannot enter multiline input
- most of the time it get hanged
- ofently arrows keys did not work instead some charactrers started appearing like:
  [image: characters appear on arrow key]

I know i can use a debugger other than this official one. But curious if I can use this one by somehow avoiding above problems.

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: `debug` is Ruby core, not Rails. It's acting within the call stack, so things you expect from a shell prompt aren't really possible as the system is hanging, waiting for input. Same as Pry or Byebug.

Comment: so you are basically saying that you never encountered this.

Comment: No, I'm saying I'm pretty sure I've encountered these issues in every debugger I've used.